Platform dependent bazel_dep
I am trying to figure out how to make use bazel_deps in a platform dependent manner - ie - in pseudo code:
If platform == x86
   bazel_dep(name = "my_dep_a", version = "1.0.0")
else
   bazel_dep(name = "my_dep_b", version = "1.1.1")

I haven't seen a way to do this in the docs and my google searches aren't turning up anything useful.  Any suggestions would be most welcome.

I think the correct approach is to make a select() over the platform. I'm surprised about such a configuration, the version shouldn't depend on the platform in that way. Care to elaborate?

On x86 - we use one set of hardware specific libraries, on arm - another different hardware - but all abstracted by our project.  So on x86 - I need hardware lib A, and on arm - I need hardware lib B.  So far - I have used platforms to exclude the building of certain pieces I download, but I am still forced to download the libs for both platforms.
So - I use select over platforms - but I don't know how to select at the MODULE level to prevent the checkout of x86 hardware libs on arm vs prevent arm hardware libs on x86.
